# how to get changed content of entire page

Tags: jquery, html

entire file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<title>DATA</title>
<link href='img/fav.png' rel='icon'>
<link href='index.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>
<div id="btnsave">SAVE</div>
<div class="test active">323</div>
<div class="test">525</div>
<div class="test">727</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
$(".test").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("contenteditable","true");
});
```

I click on `525` and change to `959`, then click on `btnsave`.

```
$("#btnsave").click(function(){
var content = $("html").html();
console.log(content);
});
```

1. Console writes the content of page without `html` tags. How can I get the content including `html` tags ?
2. Content is writen with old `525`, instead of new `959`. How can I get new, changed content of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `outerHTML` property of that node,

```
$("#btnsave").click(function(){
  var content = $("html")[0].outerHTML;
  console.log(content);
});
```

Jquery's `.html()` will return the `innerHTML` of that element.

Comment: thanks, this part is solved. Have you any solution for the second part, pls?

Comment: Or Did i misunderstand the issue?

Comment: You're right, it works but console is not cleared before writing new content, so I need to scroll down the console to see the new writing. thanks a lot. solved.

Comment: @bonaca Glad to help! :)